# GCM: Server sent messag, android client didn't recieve

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented GCM, it worked fine for a few first times, but now it doesn't work!! I also searched for this topic online and I implemented the suggestions from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiB76Gn4r_KAhWD_SwKHWB7BkEQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F18430770%2Fandroid-gcm-message-successfully-sent-but-not-received&usg=AFQjCNE6yCmfjXZzlDaxgTDuYYsINlOFqQ&sig2=aPJQsV7XERiCzRv9lvXZ_A&bvm=bv.112454388,d.bGQ&cad=rja) and [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiB76Gn4r_KAhWD_SwKHWB7BkEQFggjMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F27718960%2Fdevice-not-receive-message-from-gcm&usg=AFQjCNGiMzvHo43AEuY5QN8mlVbAwkzCFw&sig2=rxEFkrx5ewNMp8kKCX6QIA&bvm=bv.112454388,d.bGQ&cad=rja).

This is my Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="ir.masnasoft.ahkam.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ir.masnasoft.ahkam.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<receiver
            android:name="ir.masna.ahkam.managers.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION" />
                <category android:name="ir.masnasoft.ahkam" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="ir.masna.ahkam.managers.GcmMessageHandler"
            android:enabled="true"/>

        <meta-data android:name="ir.masnasoft.ahkam.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

GcmBroadcastReceiver.java:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Explicitly specify that GcmMessageHandler will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmMessageHandler.class.getName());

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

My GCMMessageHandler which show the recieved message as a notification and a Toast:

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends IntentService {

    String mes;
    private Handler handler;
    public GcmMessageHandler() {
        super("GcmMessageHandler");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        handler = new Handler();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        mes = extras.getString("message");
        // push notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) // notification icon
                .setContentTitle("مساله گو") // title for notification
                .setContentText(mes) // message for notification
                .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, Lun.class);
        //PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
        //
        showToast();
        Log.i("GCM", "Received : (" +messageType+")  "+extras.getString("message"));

        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

    }

    public void showToast(){
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mes , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

My server side correctly send the messege[id=0:1453547161124866%7fba379966d6cf16] and register my device correctly. The whole process worked fine in two past hours but doesn't work now.

Comment: Here is a [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513927/android-gcm-sent-successfully-but-not-received-on-some-devices) that you can follow and check as to why you are not receiving messages. If you really are not receiving the message(it is not delayed) there may be a problem with the device or the setup, but if it is just delayed there are some parameters that you have to consider like the `time_to_live` and `delay_while_idle`.

Comment: I don't receive the message completely