# GCM message not delivered to devices some time wifi and some time mobile data network

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

Hello I have problem for delivering `GCM` message. This issue occur only few devices and few devices work fine in same network. I have one HTC and kitkat devices which has issue when it connect in wifi if its mobile data turn on all `GCM` message delivered. 
Second one is Lenovo Lollipop phone which has problem when mobile data is turn on if we connect it to wifi then all `GCM` messages receives.
From last 2 days I am unable to find out this issue.
there is no any wifi port block issue because my another 4 devices work fine on same wifi network and individual mobile data network.
I search all stackoverflow  Questions.

Comment: GCM (and most push messaging services) works by keeping a long-lived socket open to Google's push notification server. The socket is kept open by sending "heartbeat" messages between the phone and server.

Comment: yes i know that . my code work on some devices properly without any issue with wifi or mobile data. but some devices gives problem.

Comment: First time Follow AndroidHive tutorial for GCM .but becouse of this issue i chnage my code and implement  new GCM but still same problem occurs .

Comment: Refer this : https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en#lifetime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android GCM sent successfully but not received on some devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513927/android-gcm-sent-successfully-but-not-received-on-some-devices)